# Change the plot color based on some criteria

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of values (for eg. [1 , 39, -10, 2, -5, 41]). I like to plot this in python matplotlib, with all the positive points in green and the negative points in red color. I tired my luck in stackoverflow answers, but most of them I couldn't understand(as I'm not a regular python users). Most of the answers were suggesting to use the scatter method. I didn't get how to use the c and cmap arguments in scatter. Could someone suggest me a simple method for achieving it, with some basic level of details.

Please, excuse for the noobs question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the colour attribute of the `scatter` method, for example if you want to have a black/white dots with a certain size (20) linked by lines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([1 , 39, -10, 2, -5, 41])
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = y>0

plt.scatter(x, y, c=b, s=20)
plt.gray()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Colonel, for your answer. I'm just asking is it possible to connect them with lines. I mean a line plot

Comment: Is it possible to change the line color too, i mean line above and below zero different colors.

Answer (score 2):

Divde the list of points into the negative and positive lists and plot the same with different colors:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = [1, 39, -10, 2, -5, 41, 4, -2, 6, 7, -15, -13, -20]
neg_y = []
pos_y = []

for item in y:
    if item >= 0:
        pos_y.append(item)
    else:
        neg_y.append(item)

plt.scatter(range(len(pos_y)), pos_y, color='g')
plt.scatter(range(len(neg_y)), neg_y, color='r')
plt.show()
```